# When can a hyphen ("-") be used, and what does it mean?

Tags: punctuation, hyphens, symbols

I've seen the hyphen (`-`) used in phrases a lot, for example:

> audience-knowing
>
> moves-sometimes
>
> do-gooder

When and why is the hyphen used, and what does it mean when it's used?

Comment: You might want to check this site, http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/hyphens-and-dashes/

Answer (score 2):

That's a **hyphen**. They notify the reader that two or more elements in a sentence are linked.

**Rule 1.** Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.

Examples:

> an off-campus apartment
>
> state-of-the-art design

When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is usually not necessary.

Example:

> The apartment is off campus.

There are several rules. Have a look at [this](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp).

Comment: Nice first answer!  Welcome to ELL!